# Liferay Tomcat running on the same Linux box as another CMS system

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, liferay

I'm currently running a Life ray site with Tomcat on the same box as an external website running a CMS. Tomcat is using 69% of the resources on the box and crashes regularly with very little or no users on. Any ideas the best route to take? I have a feeling it may be because 2 engines are running on the one VM and they clash. Thanks

Comment: Do the two application run in the same tomcat or do you have two instances? I have succesfully ran two tomcats (one with liferay) on a single machine.
How much ram do you have in the machine? On this machine i believe we needed to upgrade to at least 2gb because of the memory hungry-ness of liferay

Comment: two instances liferay is running tomcat and the other site is using CMS. Its got 4GB of RAM been upgraded from 2GB due to recent stress.

Comment: This kind of discussion is more appropriate for serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your JVM parameters?

In my development enviroment I use Liferay with these settings:
 -Xms256m -Xmx1500m -XX:MaxPermSize=768M

To set those settings yous have to edit the file at LIFERAY_HOME/TOMCAT_DIR/bin/setenv.sh